# How to calculate how many times I should subtract from a particular value?

Tags: javascript, math, pseudocode

In my program, each *`Job`* has an associated array of *`costs`*. I'm trying to write a function that will calculate how many times a job can be completed before it exhausts a particular resource. Each job calculates its ***cost-per-cycle*** according to how many workers are performing it, so a job with 10 workers and a cost of 2 units, will subtract 20 units from the stockpile upon completing each cycle.

However, I want the function to account for a situation where there are enough resources available for the job to partially complete. So, using the above example, there may be only 15 units of resource present, so 14 units are subtracted with 1 remainder.

roughly in pseudo-code (i'm working with Typescript but any language will do):

```py
def doJob(cost, amount, worker):
  if amount - cost * workers >= 0
     amount - cost * workers
  if amount - cost * workers < 0
     ....
```

**EDIT**:

How can I finish this function so that it correctly subtracts from the "amount" variable without it going below zero, and where the "worker" variable can be any arbitrarily high number?

Comment: As it currently stands, it’s not particularly clear what your exact question is.

Comment: `const remainder = amount % (cost * workers);`? [Javascript Remainder Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

Comment: One or more of these facts ought to be useful: (a) Integer division is how to tell how many times subtraction can happen, producing a non-negative remainder, (b) modulo division % gives the remainder. (c) `Math.max( 0, some_computation )` "clamps" the result of the computation to a non-negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the smallest `resource / resourcePerCycle` of all the resources. That doesn't take the number of workers into account yet but you just need to divide the maxJobCount by the number of workers to handle multiple workers (assuming I'm understanding your question correctly).

```js
const stockpile = [1000, 50, 50];
const jobCost = [200, 20, 2];

function maxJobCount(jobCost, stockpile) {
  return Math.min(
    ...jobCost.map((_, i) => stockpile[i] / jobCost[i])
   );
}
console.log(maxJobCount(jobCost, stockpile));
```

Comment: Would you be able to convert this to use arrays rather than objects? I think this is what i'm looking for

Comment: Switched from objects to arrays. Using arrays is more fragile because it assumes `jobCost` and `stockpile` will always have the same resources listed in the same order (even if the job cost is 0 for a certain resource). So if you wanted a job that only costs the third resource you'd have to say `jobCost = [0, 0, 10]` rather than just saying `jobCost = {gold: 10}`... but whatever works for you.

Comment: Yup, its a bad habit but I find arrays easier to wrap my head around most of the time. Thanks this seems to be working so far, much appreciated.